# How do I get CTL 220UW Built-in Speakers to work on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, display, speakers

I have a old Windows XP Computer that I just put a New Monitor onto.
My Mom had to use my speakers. So now I have NO audio output whatsoever.
I know the monitor has **built-in** speakers, But I can't access them. Do I need a Driver?

Here's some info:
Monitor - CTL 220UW
Computer - MSI Mainboard with NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200
(NVIDIA GeForce Drivers are Installed)

My Picture is normal, but I'm worrying about sound.

Comment: http://ctl.helpserve.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/111/8/my-monitor-doesnt-produce-sound

Comment: Sorry, this question is awnsered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitor will have either an input jack (green surround) for the speakers [old style] or it will be carried over HDMI [new style].

If you're lucky it will still have the old style connector, as I'm very doubtful a 5200 would have HDMI

Comment: Fortunately, It does! I thought that it carried over a special kind of VGA like my CRT Monitor.

Comment: then all you need is a stereo [TRS] mini jack & connect green to green, computer to monitor. [& See techie's link on troubleshooting]